# Using Shiba Inu Token in smart contract on main ethereum chain?

Tags: solidity, web3js, erc-20, javascript

Is this possible?

Depositing Shiba Inu Token in smart contract on main ethereum chain?
If it is, I'd like to use wBTC and wDOGE in smart contracts deployed to the main ethereum chain as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Wrapped tokens function like any other ERC20 token. You can use them in your contract

Comment: Any idea how to use it with metamask.. more specifically with ethers.js?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about your implementation

Comment: We initiate a bounty with a set amount. It defaults to ether when we deploy it. Is there any way to default to Shiba Inu token? I think it would be related to the constructor function in solidity

Comment: Can you provide the code you have so far?

Comment: // SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract Bounty {
    address payable public owner;
    address payable public provider;
    uint256 public bounty;


    constructor() payable {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
        bounty = msg.value;     
    }

    function setProvider(address providerAddy) public {
        provider = payable(providerAddy);
    }
 
    function transferToProvider() public {
        uint256 bountyUsed = bounty;
        provider.transfer(bounty);
        bounty = 0;
    }
}